# How to change OS kernel parameter "semmni" in xubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

I'm trying to install Oracle 11g on my xubuntu system but it gives me error

```
This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the OS kernel parameter 'semmni' is properly set
Expected Value : 128
Actual Value : 0
```

I tried to make changes in `sysctl.conf` file but in that file I can't find anything.

EDIT: I got to know that semmni value is 128 after i put this command - `sysctl -a | grep "kernel.sem"`

but when i run oracle 11g it says that actual value : 0

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Please add the output for `cat /proc/sys/kernel/sem`. I assume if you do `sysctl -p` it will be fixed.

Comment: @binarysta 250 32000 100 128

Comment: @binarysta i did sysctl -p and after that i ran oracle 11g installation and got the same error

Comment: Is it possible to reboot and check again? :) Also you can install with `-ignoreSysPrereqs` option.

Comment: @binarysta I reboot and checked again but still the same issue - how to use -ignoreSysPrereqs

Comment: If you specify how you are installing it may help, anyway if you are using the oracle installer you can add the option in command line https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/em.112/e12255/oui4_product_install.htm#OUICG214

Comment: @binarysta I'm not able to use that command but when i start setup there is option to ignore system prereqs - shall i do that?

Comment: You can give it a try. But why you can not use that option? Please update the question with how you are installing.

Comment: i executed it in this way
bash runinstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs

Comment: it is capital "I" in "runInstaller"

Comment: @binarysta sorry for mistake - but its not working

Comment: you better update the question with complete command and the error you recieve.